# Setting up an embedded Neo4J 2 server for testing REST API calls

Tags: java, neo4j

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I need to do to set up an embedded Neo4J 2 server that I can fire REST calls for unit testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something similar to my [in-memory server](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-in-memory-server), just use the `CommunityBootstrapper` inside your tests.

There is also a unit-testing `ServerBuilder` which is used for Neo4j's own functional tests against Neo4j server, check the [Neo4j Sources](https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial/blob/master/src/koan/java/org/neo4j/tutorial/advanced/ManagedExtensionsFormerlyKoan12.java#L44) for how it is used.